# How to gradient an image from bottom to top with css?

Tags: css, shadow, blur, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I'm looking for a way to gradient images from the bottom to top

[initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuWLZ.jpg) vs
[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hSoy.jpg)

Images run in slick slider. I've already tried with radiant gradient but without any useful results.

Comment: That's not what you call "blur". Its just a linear gradient overlay.

Comment: background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green); AND the converse background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red, green);

Answer (score 7):

It is not *blur*, it is *linear gradient* from black to transparent. You can use some element or pseudoelement (`after`/`before`) to place it over image and give it linear-gradient.
Something like this:

```css
.my-cool-item {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.my-cool-item:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 300px;
   background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), black);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-cool-item">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuWLZ.jpg"/>
</div>
```